# Likelihood computation for hidden markov models.

Tags: log-likelihood, hidden-markov-models

If we have a $2$-state model (i.e. the simplest non-trivial example) in a hidden markov model, and some generated observation-data $\mathcal{O}$ from the algorithm for generating observations. Is it then  always the case that the argument $\theta_i$ of a given family $\Theta = \{\theta_i\}_{i \in I}$ of parameters (where $I$ is some index-set), which maximes the loglikelihood, is the argument $\theta_{\ell}$ which was used to generate $\mathcal{O}$, given that $\theta_{\ell}$ is in $\Theta$.

I.e., is it always the case that $\text{argmax}_{ \theta_i\ \in \ \Theta}\Big(\text{Log}(\mathcal{O}\;|\;\theta_i)\Big) = \theta_{\ell}?$

This seems to not always be the case, I've tried this with `hmmtrain` in MATLAB, using the Baum-Welch algorithm, with `Maxiterations = 1` and investigating the likelihood-output for different initial values given to the algorithm, and found examples where this does not hold.

Edit: I believe one partial answer is that this depends on the observation-sequence $\mathcal{O}$, as well as other factors. If we focus on just this aspect, we could get a more unlikely observation-sequence, so that we will not necessarily find that $\text{argmax}_{ \theta_i\ \in \ \Theta}\Big(\text{Log}(\mathcal{O}\;|\;\theta_i)\Big) = \theta_{\ell}$. But if one takes a large enough sample, I believe one should observe that, on average, $\text{argmax}_{ \theta_i\ \in \ \Theta}\Big(\text{Log}(\mathcal{O}\;|\;\theta_i)\Big) = \theta_{\ell}$.

Comment: Please proof-read your question.  I cannot parse the first sentence of your post.  I suggest you break it down into multiple sentences.  Should "if" be "is"?  I don't know what the "is in $\Theta$" means or how that applies. I think there are too many clauses in that sentence -- please try to explain in multiple shorter sentences.  Please don't use "Edit:".  Instead, revise the question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.

Comment: What is unclear about $\Theta$. Do you understand what a "family of parameters" mean? Do you know what parameters are? Do you know what an index set is? If yes, exactly what is unclear?

I did change "HMM" to "hidden markov model", if one is unfamiliar with the acronym.

Comment: I know what all of those terms mean, but I cannot parse the grammar of the first sentence.  It has *far* too many clauses.  Moreover it is not grammatically correct, as far as I can see.  After "that the maximum...", I would expect a verb, but no verb is forthcoming.  Perhaps you mean "that the maximum is equal to [something]", but that is missing.  See my other comments as well, including not using "Edit:".   If you'd like an answer I encourage you to revise your question to address as much of the feedback as you are able.

Comment: My mother tongue is not english, so forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true.

Consider an analogous case.  Suppose you have a coin, with unknown heads probability $p$.  You flip the coin 10 times, and count how many times it came up heads, say $h$.  You compute the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{p}$ for the heads probability -- i.e., your best guess at $p$, given the results of those 10 coin flips.  Is it always the case that $\hat{p}=p$?  No, certainly not.  We have $\hat{p}=h/10$.  There is no guarantee that $p$ has the form $m/10$ for some integer $m$, and even if it does, randomness and variability means that often the number of heads will be a bit larger than $10p$ or a bit smaller than $10p$, so $\hat{p}$ will often be a bit larger than or a bit small than $p$.

If we're lucky, it's sometimes true that in the limit, as the number of observations goes to infinity, the maximum-likelihood estimate converges to the true parameter.  This is not always the case, but sometimes it is.  But that's the most we can hope.  Given a finite number of observations, we normally cannot expect the maximum likelihood estimate to be exactly equal to the true parameter.  If you're lucky, it might be close (and hopefully, the more observations you have, the closer it will be), but you shouldn't expect it to be exactly equal.